# .NET developer moving to ubuntu for development

Tags: python, ide, editor

I've been developing in .NET now for about 3 years. I love the visual studio IDE and sadly I won't be able to use it anymore.

Could someone save me hours of searching the web and reading reviews, and suggest the 'standard' or most popular IDE/Text editor for linux that will get me up and running quickly?

My main goals here are web development backed with Python.

Comment: Check out [this article](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments) which, among other things, points to [this previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584).

Comment: Developing for .net still? Or Python or something else? If .Net, why can't you use Visual Studio?

Comment: My question clearly states that I want to develop on linux :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [Wing IDE](http://www.wingware.com/doc/howtos/django) -- IMHO the best commercial IDE for Python, it does support Django if that's what you want (as, apparently, do 80% of Python-based websites; personally, I prefer [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) and the like, but maybe that's partly because my "web apps" tend to be more like "web services", with most all the UI/views parts done in HTML/CSS/Dojo;-).

Me, I use [Vim](http://www.sontek.net/post/Python-with-a-modular-IDE-(Vim).aspx) (usually in the gvim incarnation) as my "Python IDE" (and I've seen Emacs-using colleagues do at-least-equivalent wizardry, but I just can't get used to Emacs myself!-)... but I have to admit that a Wing IDE expect, particularly if faced with a thorny debug scenario, can do circles around me (and even around the Emacsers).  ((So why haven't I made the effort to switch? Maybe because, thanks to fanatical testing, I now face thorny debug scenarios too rarely to make me an expert in any new tool!-))  ((Or maybe because my fingers, having learned vi 30+ years ago, would HATE me if I switched to ANYTHING else;-)).

Comment: @Alex : Can you say something about your Vim setup ?

Comment: I second this request from dugres.  Might deserve something like a blog post, even, that you could link to here.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) question about Python IDEs.

I use Eclipse + PyDev.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you want to do web with Python, the [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) framework seems like the best choice.

From some quick Googling, the best IDE for Django would be [NetBeans with a plugin](http://kubasik.net/blog/2009/03/12/finally-a-django-ide-with-real-code-completion-and-template-support/).

Good luck on learning 'nix development, then!

Answer (score 1):

You can still develop .NET on linux.
Microsoft's [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) with support for Mac, Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I really like gedit and a terminal. You'll more than likely need to make a few [tweaks](http://grigio.org/textmate_gedit_few_steps) and maybe install a plugin or two. gedit also has a Python console window plugin if you like that kind of integration. (Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins, then enable the bottom pane with View -> Bottom Pane)

If you're new to Ubuntu I'd still recommend trying a few different tools before you get settled. The impression I get is that text editors are more commonplace than full blown IDEs on Linux. I tried a few IDEs on Ubuntu and it just didn't seem right - gedit is lightweight and I actually enjoy using it more than Textmate on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to pay Wing IDE (http://www.wingware.com/) is the best (IMO)
They have trial versions and a basic version free (https://wingware.com/wing101)

Answer (score 0):

**[Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/)**

If you've been using visual studio, then I'd guess that mono develop would be the closest thing.  As far as I know, its the best attempt around to be a linux version of visual studio.  A quick Google search gives several results for python plugins for mono develop.